# Why browser loads service worker when going offline and cause "An unknown error occurred when fetching the script."?

Tags: service-worker

I register the service worker with this code:

```
    // If the browser supports serviceWorker, and we haven't registered any - we'll register our: sw.js ..
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && !navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(function(registrationObj) {
        console.log('Registration object: ', registrationObj);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // serviceWorker registration failed ..
        console.log('Registration failed with ' + error);
    });
} else {
    console.log('Service worker already registered. Skip registration.')
};
```

I see my assets appear in the app cache. Then I go to the `Application` tab in Chrome, choose `Service Workers`, click `offline` and refresh the page.
The page opens fine, but I get this in browser console:

http://www.screencast.com/t/1uodUTHM5ig

and this in the Service Worker debugger:

http://www.screencast.com/t/zmqHMi9RJ

Comment: Sorry I have answered to "how it happens" rather than "why it happens". And for latter I do not have an answer. Reading your question again I see you  probably know that and ask for the "why" part. I have noticed that error since long time and only thing I know that it does not hinder or hurt any other code or process.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you do not have service worker in cache (And quite naturally. It is not supposed to be cached in the first place.) so it falls back to standard http fetch process, and it fails as app is offline.

That error does not hinder anything and does not effect how your app works. It is just telling you that it has failed to fetch the script. And it was not suppose to success when the app is offline anyway.

Your service worker script probably structured like this;

```
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
            if (response) {
                return response;
            }
            // request for service worker .js file falls here as it is not in the cache
            // this fails of course since the app is offline
            return fetch(event.request).then(function (response) {
                return response;
            });
        })
    );
```

Comment: So ... does that mean I have to add the service worker script to the assets I store in the cache storage ? ... cause if so - then it'd be very tricky to update it in case a new version of service worker needs to be deployed.

Comment: @peshohristov No, certainly no. That would make it impossible to update the service worker. My point is it is not, and already should not be in cache. That is why it tries to go to network as fallback, and naturally fails. And to the best of my knowledge and observations, this error does not effect anything. I can say you can ignore the error.