# Fetching cached objects in ServiceWorker - Failed

Tags: service-worker

When I try to fetch the cached by checking the offline button in dev tools.Its getting no internet connection error and I tried with turning off my wifi its getting cached data.

Comment: could anyone tell me whether the turning off the wifi and getting the cached data is fine or what instead of offline button checking

Answer (score 1):

**Offline Button**

[image: 1- offline button]
`Offline` check in Chrome inspect tools fully simulates offline network state, so you do not have to turn off your modem, wifi or network adapter while using it.

**Observing response source**

[image: Observing network panel]
You can go to Chrome inspect > Network panel and look at the `size` column to check the origin of a response. By just looking at there you will be able to tell a request is served from browser cache, service worker or from network.

**The error**

[image: Fetch error]
If you are getting error because of your `sw.js` while you are offline, it is not a problem. It simply means it could not get service worker from network and it does not have to get it while you are offline anyway. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41785597/4306828) for a more detailed information about it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to install Lighthouse extension for chrome it makes the testing way easier and the reports are quite useful.
Are you checking the 'fetch' event for the cache files? And are you sure you have the files cached ?

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  console.log(event.request.url);
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
      return response || fetch(event.request);
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: yeah I am pretty sure I cached the files